# scanf's return values and validation of inputs

Tags: c, validation, scanf

The input should have the format of integer word integer, with spaces in between. I have written the code below and as far as I can tell it works. I am now working on the error checking portion of the code.

If input is not of the correct format, how would I go about checking it?

The three error types I need to check would have these input formats: "WORD 99", "10WORD 33", and "10 WORD".

To give a little more detail. The input is of the form 10 READ 10. The first integer, 10, is the memory address the rest of the input is going to be stored at. The word, or READ in this case, is the instruction. The convertOpCode function matches the letters in the word to find a match with known instructions and saves the instruction code into the operation code register, which is *operationCode. The second integer is the address the operation uses. Read will store the user input into this second integer's address location.

Right now the convertoOpCode function throws away the first space and reads in the next characters until it reads a space. If the characters in between the spaces match a known operation it saves the corresponding operation code and returns, if no known operation is found it throws an error and exits the program.

As well, I am limited to only the variables shown. I have the int array "memory" to store the results of the compilation and the 5 int variables shown. I can't create any other arrays or buffers.

```
int compile( int memory[], int *accumulator, int *instructionCounter, 
    int *instructionRegister, int *operationCode, int *operand ){

while( scanf( "%d", accumulator) == 1 ){

    *instructionRegister = convertOpCode( instructionCounter, instructionRegister, operationCode, operand );
    if( *instructionRegister == 0 ){
        ERRORUC( accumulator );
    scanf( "%d", operand );
    if( *operationCode != 22 ){
        if( *operand > 99 ){
            ERROROPERAND( accumulator );
        memory[ *accumulator ] = ( ( *operationCode ) * 100 ) + ( *operand ); 
    }
    else{
        if( *operand > 9999 ){
            ERRORSET( accumulator );
        }
        memory[ *accumulator ] = *operand;
    }
}
checkHalt( memory, instructionCounter, accumulator );
print( memory );
return 0;
```

}

As requested here is how the convertOpCode function looks.

```
int convertOpCode( int *reg1, int* reg2, int* opCode, int* reg3 ){

    getchar();
    *reg1 = (int)getchar();
    *reg2 = (int)getchar();
    *reg3 = (int)getchar();
    *opCode = (int)getchar();

    switch( *reg1 ){
        case (int)'R':
            if( *reg2 == (int)'E' && *reg3 == (int)'A' && *opCode == (int)'D' ){
                *reg1 = (int)getchar();
                if( *reg1 == (int)' ' ){
                    *opCode = READ;
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
            }else{
               return 0;
            }
        case (int)'W'.....
```

}

Comment: What's the meaning of `WORD 99`, `10WORD 33`, and `10 WORD`, what are the expected inputs, -- and what does the function `convertOpCode()` convert?

Comment: Due to limitation set upon us I can only use 5 integers throughout the entire program. @rubberboots hopefully I explained it better in the new edit to the question.

Comment: Why not grab all the values at once?  Use fgets like chux suggests then "sscanf( buffer, "%s %s %s", one, two, three );".  Then you can use things like "isalpha()" and the return value of the sscanf to decide how to treat the scanned elements.  Also it seems horribly unsafe to me to treat the input of a program as an index into an array - especially w/o bounds testing.

Comment: @n0741337 I can't read it all in at once since I can't create a buffer. I have 5 integer variables I can use and that is it. That's why I read in the address value and store it in the accumulator. Then I use the 4 left over variables to read in the word as integers and convert it to the correct code. Once that is done I can then reuse unused variables to assign the operand and store everything in the memory array. For this task we are to assume that the indexing values are correct, so I don't really have to check the bounds.

Comment: @user1362058 - I saw your extended requirements after I posted my comment.  Can you show us the convertOpCode() function?  If you only have 5 integers to work with maybe you don't need 4 of them used by convertOpCode().  For example, are " R" and " W" enough to uniquely identify the operation in the input?

Comment: Is using `scanf()` another requirement for your system, in addition to not creating extra variables (you realize the `scanf()` itself is creating a buffer to store the input before parsing it for you)?

Comment: If scanf() is okay, here's a sketchy way to use all five ints in one pass: `fifth = scanf( "%d %c%[EADORD] %d", &first, &second, &third, &fourth );`.  I say sketchy because assigning the scanset to &third goes against the man pages ( bad ) and likely won't work everywhere.  It works on a linux box I have access to and valgrind didn't throw any errors( with no flags ).  Also, it will throw strict compiler errors like when assigning "%c" to the second int.

Comment: I tried using R or W to identify the codes but I also need to verify the instruction is a valid one. Therefore, READ could be identified as READ but so would ROAR.

Comment: Btw, just nitpicking, a character literal like 'A' is of type int anyway (it looks like a char but essentially is the same as writing 65).

Answer (score 0):

I think I would not abuse the other ints for reading the characters of the opcodes.  I don't know the requirements of the task exactly obviously, but I have taught C in the past, and I'd not make a requirement like that if there isn't another way (your boss may differ though :-)).

I think you could parse the caracters as you read them, building a case structure that is sort of a tree of the allowed words.  Lets say (for example and simplicty) you have the instructions 
ASK MUL SUB

```
int getopcode()
{
    if (getchar()==' ') {  // ok, starting with space

        switch (getchar()) { 

            case 'A': // probably A(DD) but make sure ...
                if (getchar()=='D' && getchar()=='D') {
                    return 1; // opcode for ADD
                }
                break;


            case 'M': // probably M(UL) but make sure ...
                if (getchar()=='U' && getchar()=='L') {
                    return 2; // opcode for MUL
                }
                break;

            ....
        }
    }

    return 0;  // error if we arrive here. 
}
```

If you have operations that start with the same letter (ADD and ASK) you'd need a 2nd switch stacked inside the 'A' switch to proceed based on the 2nd letter.

For the main program, I just resketched that a bit for more error checking (not sure about some of your macros like ERRORUC but I'm sure you'll get the picture):

```
while( scanf( "%d", accumulator) == 1 ){

    *instructionRegister = getopcode();
    if (*instructionRegister!=0) {

        if (scanf(" %d", operand )==1) {  // ok, one more decimal operand

            switch (*operationCode) {   // operand error checking per opcode

                case 22: 
                        if( *operand> 99 )
                            ERROROPERAND(accumulator);
                         break;

                default:
                        if( *operand > 9999 )
                            ERRORSET(accumulator);
                        break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // error reading 2nd operand
            ERRORUC( accumulator );
        }

    }
    else {
        // error in opcode
        ERRORUC( accumulator );
    }


    if ( no error set in accumulator, i.e. no ERRORxx macro called) {
         // accumulator, instructionRegister and operand are ok here
         // write to memory
    }
    else 
        break; // break the loop, end compiling
}

print( memory );
return 0;
```

Something need to be done to break the loop based on error or not make it a loop initially.